# Implementing GROUP BY in MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, symfony

I'm trying to use GROUP BY in query below but I've got confused when I read about map reduce and looked at some examples so please can someone help me to implement GROUP BY in example below?

I want to group brand field so it will look like this:

```
SELECT
...
...
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY brand ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Thanks in advance

```
    $qb->field('brand')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/^Nike/i'));
    $qb->field('userDefined')->equals('Yes');
    $qb->limit(10);
    $qb->sort('brand', 'asc');
    $qb->eagerCursor(true);
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $cursor = $query->execute();
```

Based on example document below, the query should return:

```
Nike 1
Nike 2
```

- Puma is ignored because userDefined is not equal to Yes and two matching Nike 1 grouped.

Document examples:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53dfb8f7b6578c17b200001f" ),
  "num" : "1ABc1",
  "name" : "Max",
  "brand" : "Nike 1"
  "image" : "http://....../my-image.jpg",
  "blend" : "Cotton",
  "stitches" : "25"
  "created" : Date( 1407170807000 ),
  "userDefined" : 'Yes'
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "12dfb8f7b6578c17b2000055" ),
  "num" : "4GBc1",
  "name" : "Max",
  "brand" : "Nike 1"
  "image" : "http://....../my-image-2.jpg",
  "blend" : "Cotton",
  "stitches" : "25"
  "created" : Date( 1407170807088 ),
  "userDefined" : 'No'
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "99dfb8f7b6578c17b2000055" ),
  "num" : "0GBa2",
  "name" : "Max",
  "brand" : "Nike 1"
  "image" : "http://....../my-image-3.jpg",
  "blend" : "Cotton",
  "stitches" : "25"
  "created" : Date( 1407171807088 ),
  "userDefined" : 'Yes'
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "22dfb8f7b6578c17b2000055" ),
  "num" : "0aaa2",
  "name" : "Max",
  "brand" : "Nike 2"
  "image" : "http://....../my-image-4.jpg",
  "blend" : "Cotton",
  "stitches" : "25"
  "created" : Date( 1407171807088 ),
  "userDefined" : 'Yes'
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "11dfb8f7b6578c17b2000055" ),
  "num" : "0aaa2",
  "name" : "Max",
  "brand" : "Puma"
  "image" : "http://....../my-image-3.jpg",
  "blend" : "Cotton",
  "stitches" : "25"
  "created" : Date( 1407171807088 ),
  "userDefined" : 'Yes'
},
```

I've went thru these:

- [Map Reduce](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/map-reduce.html)
- [db.collection.group()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/)
- [$group (aggregation)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform a group in MongoDB, you have to use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) instead of find. This will allow you to use the [$group operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as one step of the aggregation pipeline.

The MongoDB shell syntax for this aggregation pipeline would be this:

```
db.collection.agregate(
        { $match: {
                userDefined: 'No'
            }
        },
        { $group: {
                _id: '$brand' 
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: I added document example above. Thank for the help.

Comment: The problem is how am I going to apply it to my Symfony code above!

Comment: Check out how to do [aggregation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php) in the MongoDB PHP driver, which Symfony/Doctrine wrap.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        brand: 1,
        userDefined: 1
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        userDefined: "Yes"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$brand"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        brand: "$_id"
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "brand": 1
    }
},
{
    $limit: 10
}
```

])

Comment: The problem is how am I going to apply it to my Symfony code above!